# Tags Incorporated in String in Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text-styling, text-widget

Tkinter `Text` widget allows to style text using tags.

```
text.tag_config('red', foreground='red')
text.insert(END, 'Red text', 'red')
```

Is it possible to include the tag in the string literal?

Pseudocode:

```
text.insert(END, 'This sentence has <red tag>red text</red tag> in it.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. However, it's pretty easy to write code that searches for patterns in the text widget and to replace them with tkinter tags.